# Cooktop Install Into Granite Counters - Special install kit needed?

Tags: installation, stove, granite, cooktops

Long story short, I am trying to install a new Frigidaire induction cooktop into a granite countertop.

The manual says the granite cooktop installation kit can be ordered, but I'm not sure I understand why the install kit is needed and why it is so expensive.

- How is the sealant used?  Is it used to attach the brackets to the granite?  Or to seal the cooktop to the granite so dirt/grime do not get in?
- Am I supposed to drill into the granite to mount the brackets?
- Why can't I just use/modify the existing brackets?
- Why does the granite install kit have 6 different brackets in 3 different sizes?  Are all 6 brackets supposed to be used or just 2?

[Link to cooktop installation manual](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/3b/3b015bd3-b808-4d6a-924d-ffea41100552.pdf)

[Link to the $155 granite cooktop installation kit](https://www.electrolux.com/en/p/accessories/cooking-accessories/cooking-accessories-and-consumables/cooking-installation-parts/903061-9010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All cooktops I have worked with, both traditional coil electric and gas, simply drop into an appropriate sized cutout.

This cooktop requires a certain amount of space on all sides to keep the cooktop body from being too close to the counter. The border area of the cooktop overlaps the countertop (as with other types of cooktops) but without these spacers/brackets, the cooktop would either be loose within the cutout or, if the cutout were simply made smaller to fit the cooktop body, there would be a fire hazard. Or at least that's the way I understand the installation manual.

Why they couldn't have simply built the necessary extra space into the cooktop body is something only the manufacturer can answer (and likely won't answer, but that's a separate problem). My best guess is that a bean counter determined that the extra steel to make a larger cooktop body with empty space in it would cost more than providing a set of brackets/clips.

The catch is that these brackets need to attach to the counter. For a typical non-stone counter (Formica, other laminates, butcher block, etc.) simple screws work fine. Granite (and other stone) requires a different type of mounting kit for the brackets. All of which could be avoided with a slightly different design, but once you are committed to this cooktop you have to install it properly to avoid problems.

Comment: Lovely.  I was hoping for a cooktop to just drop in as there's an oven directly beneath it and I really don't want to pull that out.  So these brackets are to ensure correct spacing?  Or are they structural to prevent the cooktop weight from resting completely on the glass?

Comment: Looks like both, but stated reason in the manual is spacing.

Comment: My interpretation was the manual was referring to the spring spacers for spacing, not the brackets.  It does not state why the brackets are required, except to meet local codes

Comment: The spacers need the brackets - if you plop the cooktop with spacers in a hole without the brackets, the spacers won't be stable.